# Consider the convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the convergence of sequence: 
$$1.\: \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln n!}$$

$$2.\: \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\ln\ln n\right)^{\ln n}}$$

My tried:

Set $u_n=\frac{1}{\ln n!}$

We have $n\left(\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}-1\right)=\frac{n\ln\left(n+1\right)}{\ln n!}>\frac{n\ln n}{\ln n!}>\frac{\ln1+\ln2+...+\ln n}{\ln n!}=1$

Hence this sequence is convergence. But result this sequence is divergence :(

Comment: Those are not sequences but (infinite) **series**

Comment: what is the criterion you try to use? I totally, don't get it. What you could try for the first series is $ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n ln(k)$

Comment: Reread the precise formulation of the theorem that you thought you'd use here.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 The criterion is caller Raabe's criterion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raabe%27s_test#Extensions_for_L.3D1

Comment: Thanks, I tried to understand what he was doing and then I saw that it looks like Raabe's criterion :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\log n!=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\implies \frac1{\log n!}=\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^n\log k}\ge\frac 1{n\log n}$$

and now you can use the [Cauchy Condensation Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) (CCT)"

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log 2^n}=\frac1{\log 2}\frac1{n}$$

which is a multiple of the harmonic series and thus diverges.

Now you try the second one, mixing perhaps several tests...